# With github is there a way that you can watch just a branch?

Tags: github

With github is there a way that you can watch just a branch?  There is a particular repository that I have starred that pushes dozens of commits per day so I don't want to watch it and receive that many notifications.  But I would like to watch a specific proof-of-concept branch.  Is this possible today with github notifications?

Answer (score 2):

I do not know if you can just watch a branch using Github's own watch mechanism, but it is really simple to make up a script that tells you if a branch has been modified or not, using Github's API. 
Here's a simple Python script. What you need to do is to write in a file the current time and date, 
e.g Sat, 11 Oct 2014 21:10:00 GMT , and then just put this script into a daemon.

The only thing you need to do is to add the e-mailing part. (https://docs.python.org/2/library/email-examples.html)

```
    import requests
    repo = ""
    user = ""
    branch = ""
    lastModified = (open("modified.txt", "r")).read()
    headers = {"If-Modified-Since": lastModified}
    request = requests.get("https://api.github.com/repos/" + user + "/" + repo + "/commits? sha="+branch, headers=headers )
    if(request.status_code != 304 && request.status_code == 200):
         modified = (open("modified.txt", "w")).write(request.headers["last-modified"])
         print("Branch has been updated. Sending e-mail")
```

Hope you figured it out by now.

Edit: Reading my response,it may be a bit abstract. 
Github API provides a parameter in the header response "last-modified". You can use this to verify if what are you querying for has been modified against a specific date. (more info at https://developer.github.com/v3/#conditional-requests)

When you send a GET request, you must include in the headers the parameter "If-Modified-Since" together with a value, e.g. Sat, 11 Oct 2014 21:10:00 GMT

If there has been no modification, you will get the status_code 304. 
If it has been modified, you will get status_code 200.

It is worth mentioning that if status_code is 304, the query does not count towards the query limit of Github's API, which is 60 for unauthenticated users, and 5000 for authenticated ones. (more at https://developer.github.com/v3/#rate-limiting)